# How to create moq of datacontext wrapper class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, moq

I am trying to write unit tests using NUnit and Moq. I am using LINQ to SQL in my project.

First I created a wrapper class just like the one in this blog

http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/07/06/mocking-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx

Here's my code

```
[Test]
public void MakeModelsListTest()
{
    var objTbl1 = new List<tblSomeTable> 
        {                 
            new tblSomeTable { Make = "Nissan", Model = "Rogue"},
            new tblSomeTable { Make = "Hyundai", Model= "Elantra GT"},
            new tblSomeTable { Make = "Ram", Model="Ram Pickup 3500"},
            new tblSomeTable { Make = "Ford", Model="Freestar"},
            new tblSomeTable { Make = "Chrysler", Model="Aspen Hybrid"},
            new tblSomeTable { Make = "Buick", Model="Verano"}            
        }.AsQueryable();

    var objDataContext = new Mock<DataContextWrapper<CarvanaDataContext>>();
    var dbContext = objDataContext.As<IDataContextWrapper>();

    dbContext.Setup(i => i.Table<tblSomeTable>()).Returns(objTbl1);            

    MpcController objMpc = new MpcController();
    AutoTraderMakeModels makeModels = objMpc.MakeModels( objDataContext.Object);

    Assert.That(makeModels, Is.InstanceOf(typeof(AutoTraderMakeModels)));
    Assert.That(makeModels.results.Count(), Is.GreaterThan(0));
    Assert.That(makeModels.results[0].models.Count(), Is.GreaterThan(0));
}
```

On this line

```
AutoTraderMakeModels makeModels = objMpc.MakeModels( objDataContext.Object);
```

I am getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I am very new to Moq. Please suggest!